# Decrypt ciphertext to plaintext with known key

Tags: c++, encryption

```
string S, K, generated;
cout << "Enter the message: ";
cin >> S;
cout << "Enter the key: ";
cin >> K;
cout << "The message is: " << S << endl; // output the string
int seed = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < (int) K.length(); i++)
    seed += K[i]; // used to generate a certain sequence of numbers
srand(seed); // new seed per new key
cout << "The cipher is: ";
for(int i = 0; i < (int) S.length(); i++) {
    int R = rand() % K.length();
    char L = 65 + (S[i] - 65 + K[R] - 65) % 26;
    cout << L;
    generated += L; // to actually have something to use for decryption
}
// FINALLY, to reach to this step and do something like this took me over 2 hours of continuous debugging
cout << endl;
cout << "The message again is: ";
for(int i = 0; i < (int) generated.length(); i++) {
    int R = rand() % K.length();
    char L = 65 + (generated[i] - 65 + K[R] - 65) % 26;
    cout << L;
}
cout << endl;
```

Sorry for the messy code. Anyway, so here's what I did so far:

- User inserts message and key
- User gets a ciphertext

But now I'm actually stuck with the fact that I want to decrypt the ciphertext using the correct key. Basically, I want to return the ciphertext to plaintext. I put the effort to do this myself and the approach is listed under the 'The message again is:' but it gives me a wrong result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is strange but it can actually work. Provided that the encoder and decoder are made by the same compiler, and probably on the same computer.

You are using the key to generate the seed for `srand`. This seed can be reproduced. The proceeding random numbers will be predictable.

When decoding the message, you are supposed to `srand` again with the same seed.

```
int main()
{
    string S, K, generated;
    S = "MESSAGE";
    K = "KEY";
    cout << "The message is: " << S << endl; // output the string

    {
        int seed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)K.length(); i++)
            seed += K[i]; // used to generate a certain sequence of numbers
        srand(seed); // new seed per new key
    }

    cout << "The cipher is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)S.length(); i++) 
    {
        int R = rand() % K.length();
        char L = 65 + (S[i] - 65 + K[R] - 65) % 26;
        cout << L;
        generated += L; // to actually have something to use for decryption
    }

    {//we can use the key to regenerate the same seed:
        int seed = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)K.length(); i++)
            seed += K[i]; 
        srand(seed); //**** this is critical ****
    }

    cout << endl << "The message again is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)generated.length(); i++) 
    {
        int R = rand() % K.length();
        char L = 65 + (generated[i] - 65 + (26 - (K[R] - 65)) ) % 26;//reverse shift
        cout << L;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do have to say that in the decryption phase, I did not use any random generated numbers any more due to the fact that I stored them in an array to avoid confusion with srand(). The reverse shift method worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You could also do this without random numbers, and then your code would be very similar to "Vigenere" cipher.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure since I didn't get to actually compile a new solution, but my guess would be because you are using a new random number during your decryption phase. You need to preserve the original random number used in encryption in order to make the function invertable.

Comment: I debugged it and it appears that the sequence of the random numbers generated are equal. However, I believe that mistakes happen so I stored it in an array just to be sure.